# jquery day calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a **jquery day calendar** with same functionalities as the [jquery week calendar](http://jquery-week-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.weekcalendar/full_demo/weekcalendar_full_demo.html)

I have gone through certain day calendars but they donot contain the resources of **jquery week calendar**

This may be be a stupid question but can I modify **jquery week calendar**
such that it can be used as a day calendar?

I was able to change the previous week and next week buttons to previous day and next day buy using my own functions but the events are not loaded and i am not sure of how to do that.

If someone has done this before please do highlight me on this.

I have posted the changes I made in the jquery.js file here [jquery.js](http://pastebin.com/kjvdANvV)

In demo.js

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();

$calendar.weekCalendar({
    timeslotsPerHour : 4,
    allowCalEventOverlap : true,
    overlapEventsSeparate: true,
    firstDayOfWeek : n,
    businessHours :{
        start: 6, 
        end: 22, 
        limitDisplay: true
    },
    daysToShow : 1,
```

Comment: What's the main feature you want? To work exactly like the week calendar, but only display one day at a time?

Comment: @PatrickM: Yes, thats what I was looking for.

Comment: Showing only one day is not difficult. But after that when next or prev button is clicked it will show the current day of the week in the next week. ie: if i click next today it will goto next mon...
I want it to goto next day instead of next week

Comment: Check out http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ I think it will work better for you

Comment: @Juan Gonzales: I have gone through it but dosenot have several resources that jquery week calendar like edit, save, delete.

Comment: That stuff you have to add, but it is actually incredibly useful and very close to google calendar. You have 5 different view options. And much much more

Comment: All you would have to do is add a div with those buttons and functions at the bottom of your page hide it and on dayClick or select show the box with the corresponding times

Comment: Not including the resources and support that are available on SO and google code to guide you

Comment: @Juan Gonzales: Thanks I think that is the only possible solution for me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25930/discussion-between-developer-and-juan-gonzales)

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question that you need week calender , did you hear before about JQuery Full Calender plugin ?? you can work with Year, Month even one day it got many Properties and function to handle with and easy to customize i make a task list using it ..

This is the Link [FullCalender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

And here is its Documentation :
[FullCalender Documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/)